# Is it necessary to discard outliers before applying LSTM on time series

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, statistics, outliers

I am trying to detect anomalies on a time series that controls battery voltage output. I find that my original dataset has some outliers. In this case do I need to remove those points using InterQuartile Range (IQR) or Zscore? of course before using the LSTM keras model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing or not removing outliers all depends on what you are trying to achieve. You write here that your goal is anomaly detection, so at first glance, it seems like a poor idea to remove points or values that you are trying to detect. However, if you detect values that are of such a nature that they cannot even be due to plausible anomalies, then yes, you should remove them. In all other cases, you should consider to keep them.

Comment: I think in my case I need to keep them because actually I do not know if they are anomalies or not. I only used boxplot and it classified them as anomaly points with respect to the remained points.